# How to resolve java.lang.ClassCastException while processing Sys refcursor?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have the below code

```
StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("pkg_p.proc_p");
         storedProcedure.getResultList();
```

stored proc returns a ref cursor equivalent to the below query

```
 select 1 as id_col, 'My Name ' as name , 1000 as sal from dual;
```

I have a pojo class  MyTable which is equivalent to the result set return type of the query

```
 public class MyTable {
 private Long idCol;
 private String name;
 private Long sal;

 /// setter and getters omitted for brevity
```

}

```
for(Object[]row: resultSet)
        {
MyTable mt = new MyTable ();
mt.setIdCol((Long)row[0]);  ///throw class cast exception
}
```

How to resolve the below error

> Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Long

Even though row[0] has Long values like 1,2,10,687 etc

Comment: You can change the Data-Type `Long` to `Number` for both `idCol` and `sal` or you can simply cast the value to `Long` by invoking `longValue()` method on the object.

Comment: what is the the problem? idCol has integer value in DB .why spring is treating as Big Decimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't cast Big Decimal to Long how ever you can get the Long value from it using

```
row[0].longValue()
```

if that doesn't work cast row to big decimal and

```
(BigDecimal) row[0].longValue()
```

so your code would look something like this

```
mt.setIdCol((BigDecimal)row[0].longValue());
```

or try to change the loop to

```
for(BigDecimal[] row : resultSet)
```

if you don't want to use casting

after reading your comments.

```
    for(Object[] row: resultSet) {
        MyTable mt = new MyTable();
        if(resultSet instanceof BigDecimal) {
            mt.setIdCol((BigDecimal)row[0].longValue());
        } else if (resultSet instanceof String){
            ....
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks it seems sping is by default treating any numeric value as Big Decimal.Right?

Comment: i am not able to row[0].longValue() .Eclipse doesnt give option

Comment: Do you have the correct case? try `mt.setIdCol(row[0].longValue()); ` if that doesn't work cast it to BigDecimal like this `Do you have the correct case? try `mt.setIdCol((BigDecimal )row[0].longValue()); ``

Comment: Edited answer let me know if you are still having problems

Comment: I have provided a variety of solutions for you to try and see what you like eclipse wasn't giving you the option because the loop item was an Object.

Comment: ok let me try....what the the problem.....idCol has integer valu in DB ....why spring is treating as Big Decimal?

Comment: `for(BigDecimal[] row : resultSet)`  i can't use this as i have string in result set

Comment: I have Edited my answer.